# Okular can't read pdf files

Tags: 14.04, kde, pdf, okular

I recently have installed Okular on my Ubuntu 14.04.

The problem is when I open pdf files, okular gives me the error "Can not find a plugin which is able to handle the document being passed."

When I ran Okular by Terminal, this is the message I get.

```
admin@me:~$ okular ex01.pdf
okular(14100)/kdeui (KIconLoader): Error: standard icon theme "oxygen" not found! 
okular(14100)/kdeui (KIconLoader): Error: standard icon theme "oxygen" not found!

okular(14100) KPixmapSequence::Private::loadSequence: Invalid pixmap specified. 
okular(14100) KPixmapSequence::Private::loadSequence: Invalid pixmap specified. 
okular(14100) KPixmapSequence::frameSize: No frame loaded 
okular(14100) KPixmapSequence::Private::loadSequence: Invalid pixmap specified. 
okular(14100) KPixmapSequence::frameSize: No frame loaded 
okular(14100) KPixmapSequence::Private::loadSequence: Invalid pixmap specified. 
okular(14100) KPixmapSequence::frameSize: No frame loaded 
okular(14100) KPixmapSequence::Private::loadSequence: Invalid pixmap specified. 
okular(14100) KPixmapSequence::frameSize: No frame loaded 
okular(14100) KPixmapSequence::Private::loadSequence: Invalid pixmap specified. 
okular(14100) KPixmapSequence::frameSize: No frame loaded 
okular(14100) KPixmapSequence::Private::loadSequence: Invalid pixmap specified. 
okular(14100) KPixmapSequence::frameSize: No frame loaded 
okular(14100): No ksycoca4 database available! 

okular(14100)/kdecore (trader) KServiceTypeTrader::defaultOffers: KServiceTypeTrader: serviceType  "okular/Generator"  not found 
okular(14100)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
okular(14100)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
okular(14100)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
okular(14100)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
okular(14100)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
okular(14100): No ksycoca4 database available! 

okular(14100)/kdecore (trader) mimeTypeSycocaServiceOffers: KMimeTypeTrader: mimeType "application/pdf" not found 
okular(14100): No ksycoca4 database available! 

okular(14100)/kdecore (trader): KMimeTypeTrader: couldn't find service type "okular/Generator" 
Please ensure that the .desktop file for it is installed; then run kbuildsycoca4. 
okular(14100)/okular (app) Okular::Document::openDocument: No plugin for mimetype '"application/pdf"'.
okular(14100): Couldn't start knotify from knotify4.desktop:  "KLauncher could not be reached via D-Bus. Error when calling start_service_by_desktop_path:
The name org.kde.klauncher was not provided by any .service files
" 
okular(14100)/kdeui (KNotification) KNotification::slotReceivedIdError: Error while contacting notify daemon "The name org.kde.knotify was not provided by any .service files" 

X Error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter) 3
Major opcode: 20 (X_GetProperty)
Resource id:  0x2a0002e
okular(14110) KPixmapSequence::Private::loadSequence: Invalid pixmap specified. 
okular(14110) KPixmapSequence::frameSize: No frame loaded 
okular(14110) KPixmapSequence::Private::loadSequence: Invalid pixmap specified. 
okular(14110) KPixmapSequence::frameSize: No frame loaded 
okular(14110) KPixmapSequence::Private::loadSequence: Invalid pixmap specified. 
okular(14110) KPixmapSequence::frameSize: No frame loaded 
X Error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter) 3
Major opcode: 20 (X_GetProperty)
Resource id:  0x2a0001d
X Error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter) 3
Major opcode: 20 (X_GetProperty)
Resource id:  0x2a0001d
```

I would be much appreciated for any suggestion to solve this problem. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Can you add to question the command you typed to get error, Thanks.

Comment: Is `libpoppler-qt4-4` installed?

Answer (score 25):

This was quite the annoying one, but:

```
sudo apt-get install kdelibs5-plugins kdelibs5-data oxygen-icon-theme
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error message. In my case *Okular* was installed with `sudo`, and the KDE dependencies were installed into the home folder under `.kde`, but with root as owner and group.

I changed by running:

```
sudo chown -R youruser .kde    
sudo chgrp -R youruser .kde
```

then it worked normal.

Answer (score 4):

According to linux mint release notes in section "Issues with KDE Apps"

> If you're experiencing issues with KDE apps (Okular, Gwenview, KStars..etc) run the following command:

```
apt install kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins
```

Note: These issues do not affect the KDE edition. A regression in KDE 4.14 prevents these applications from working fine out of the box outside of KDE.

Answer (score 2):

Open Synaptic Package Manager, and search for `kde-core-devel`

Install all packages under the version `4:4.14.2-0ubuntu1~ubuntu14.04~ppa1`. Then search for `oxygen`, and install the oxygen icon theme.